# (discord.js) Create a command that can be only used after another specific one has been executed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I dont know how to do that and i already looked for it but found nothing.
I want to create a command, that can be only executed after a specific other one has been executed. Something like

*User: &help*

*Bot: select category: 1 / 2 / 3*

*User: 1*

*Bot: shows embed including text for category 1*

**Important:** if the user types "1" but didnt executed "&help" the bot doesnt accept it.

Thank yu

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html) to await user messages after the help command. Here's an example:

```js
// Help command execute method
message.channel.send('select category: 1 / 2 / 3');

const originalSender = message.author.id;

// Filter the message to get only the ones that were sent by the person who
// executed the help command.
const filter = message => message.author.id === originalSender;
// How many time will it await for user messages in milliseconds
const time = 15000;

const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time });

collector.on('collect', message => {
  if (message.content === '1') {
     message.channel.send('shows embed including text for category 1');
     collector.stop();
  }
  if (message.content === '2') {
     message.channel.send('shows embed including text for category 2');
     collector.stop();
  }
  if (message.content === '3') {
     message.channel.send('shows embed including text for category 2');
     collector.stop();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The probably easiest way to do this would be to just create a boolean that changes when the user executed a command

For example:

```
var x = 0;



client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content == 'COMMAND') {
        //Do something
        x = 1;   
     };
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content == 'SECONDCOMMAND' && Boolean(x)) {   
        //Do something else
        x = 0;
    };
});
```